# How to link two SVG elements so that mouseover on one can reference also the other?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

In my code, I create a text label and a transparent rect behind it so that user can easily select it. As the mouseover is defined on the rect, I cannot do anything with the text (obviously). How should I best "link" the text to the rectangle? I would need every rect to be linked to a respective text, but I could not find a way of doing in this way:

```
//for every data point, one label and one rect are created
settings.g.selectAll(".labels")
            .data(data)
            .join(
                enter => {
                    let g = enter.append("g");
                    let text = g.append("text")
                    let rect = g.append("rect");

                    text
                        .text(d => d.name)
                    rect
            
                        .attr("width", (d) => d.bbox.width)
                        .attr("height", (d) => d.bbox.height)
                        .attr("fill", "transparent")
                        .on('mouseover', function (d) {
                           //TODO: make the respective text BOLD
                        })
```

I know I could selectAll("text") and find the right one but that would not be efficient as there are many "texts".

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. As it is it is difficult to see the issue. You should investigate event delegation

Comment: How about simply using `text` (the local variable within the scope of `enter => { ... }`) inside the mouseover callback?

Comment: @qrsngky That would refer to all "texts", I already tried that.

Comment: We would need to see the svg code. However I suppose the problem comes from the transparent rect. Please try `pointer-events="all"` for the rect. If this is not solving your problem please consider adding the svg code to your question

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the "best" way, but here is a demo.
This works because `rect.nodes()[0]` matches `text.nodes()[0]` and so on, and `e.target` is the relevant `SVGRectElement`.

```js
let data = [
    { name: "A", bbox: { x: 20, y: 20, width: 20, height: 40 } },
    { name: "B", bbox: { x: 60, y: 20, width: 20, height: 40 } },
    { name: "C", bbox: { x: 100, y: 20, width: 20, height: 40 } },
    { name: "D", bbox: { x: 140, y: 20, width: 20, height: 40 } },
]
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

    d3.select('#focus').selectAll(null).enter()
        .data(data)
        .join(enter => {

            let g = enter.append("g");
            let text = g.append("text")
            let rect = g.append("rect");

            text.text(d => d.name).attr('x', d => d.bbox.x + d.bbox.width / 2).attr('y', d => d.bbox.y + d.bbox.height / 2)
            rect.attr("width", (d) => d.bbox.width)
                .attr("height", (d) => d.bbox.height)
                .attr('x', d => d.bbox.x).attr('y', d => d.bbox.y)
                .attr("fill", "transparent")
                .on('mouseover', function (e, d) {
                  let idx = rect.nodes().indexOf(e.target);
                  let textElement = text.nodes()[idx]
                  d3.select(textElement).attr('font-weight', 'bold');
                }).on('mouseout', function (e, d) {
                  let idx = rect.nodes().indexOf(e.target);
                  let textElement = text.nodes()[idx]
                  d3.select(textElement).attr('font-weight', null);
                })

            return g;
        })

});
```

```css
svg{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

svg text{
  dominant-baseline: central;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

svg rect{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

<body>
<svg id='focus'>
 
</svg>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the mouseover on the `g` element containing "rect" and "text".
Event is triggered on either rect or text hovering. You can then retrieve the text element and do whatever you want.

```
g.on('mouseover',function (){
    d3.select(this).select('text').style('font-weight','bold')
})
```